# Error in button that transfers data to firebase in html,js

Tags: javascript, html

This button works:

```html
<form id="contactForm">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Button with id `guestAnswerIsNotComing_id` does not work:

```html
<button id="notConfirming_Button"  onclick="document.getElementById('NotConfirmingArrival').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;" > no </button>
<div id="NotConfirmingArrival" class="modal">
    <form class="modal-content animate" action="/action_page.php" method="post">

        <div class="imgcontainer" >     
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('NotConfirmingArrival').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>  
            <p>Are you sure</p>
        </div>

        <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">                    
            <form id="contactForm">
                <button id="guestAnswerIsNotComing_id" type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('NotConfirmingArrival').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">yes</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: How exactly it doesn't work? Does it produce any error? Could you include the error in your question?

Comment: It shows no error
He shows
File not found
It may have been moved or deleted

Comment: When I change the
type = "submit
To - type = "button

It does not give an error but also does not work